# How Do I Return a Collection from a PL/SQL Package

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am currently trying to come up with a way of returning a collection of data from a PL/SQL Package.  The following is representative of what is specified in the package and what I am trying to do:

This is the package specification:

```
   TYPE MYRECORD IS RECORD
   (
   ID NUMBER,
   SOME_TEXT1 VARCHAR2(50),
   SOME_TEXT2 VARCHAR2(50),
   SOME_TEXT3 VARCHAR2(50),  
   SOME_TEXT4 VARCHAR2(255),
   );

  TYPE VTABLE is table of MYRECORD;

 FUNCTION lookup_values (
                  ANUMBER IN   VARCHAR2,
                  SOMETEXT1        IN   VARCHAR2,
                  SOMETIME  IN   VARCHAR2,
 ) RETURN VTABLE
```

My problem comes when I make references to an instance of VTABLE in the function:

This is in the package body:

```
 FUNCTION Lookup_Values(
                  ANUMBER       IN   VARCHAR2,
                  SOME_TEXT1        IN   VARCHAR2,
                  SOME_TIME  IN   VARCHAR2,

         ) RETURN  VTABLE
IS


      v_records  VTABLE;
      r_record    MYRECORD;

      CURSOR OUR_RECORDS IS
      SELECT * FROM OUR_TABLE

 BEGIN

      OPEN OUR_RECORDS 
      LOOP
      FETCH OUR_RECORDS 
      INTO r_record;
      EXIT WHEN OUR_RECORDS %NOTFOUND;

 -- I want to do something like the pseudo code below.  Is it possible?
     v_records.Extend(1);
     v_records.ID := r_record.ID;
     v_records.SOME_TEXT1 := r_record.SOMETEXT1;
     v_records.SOME_TEXT2 := r_record.SOMETEXT2;
     v_records.SOME_TEXT3 := r_record.SOMETEXT3;
     v_records.SOME_TEXT4 := r_record.SOMETEXT4;

    END LOOP;

    RETURN (v_records);
 END;
```

Hope I have managed to convey what I am trying to achieve.  Apologies of this is not the case.  If anything isn't clear just feed it back and I will try to clarify.

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: It is very much possible. Your approach is correct. I have not checked from general syntax perspective but this should work and give you the desired results.

Comment: I believe you are just missing the initialization of the collection. Try `v_records VTABLE := VTABLE();`

Comment: As @ChrisHep indicated you need to initialize v_records,  but you also need to reference the index into v_records where you are assigning values e.g. `v_records(v_records.last).id := r_record.id;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code with the comments provided would work, but using BULK COLLECT would be more performant.

```
FUNCTION Lookup_Values(
                  ANUMBER       IN   VARCHAR2,
                  SOME_TEXT1        IN   VARCHAR2,
                  SOME_TIME  IN   VARCHAR2,

         ) RETURN  VTABLE
IS
      v_records  VTABLE;

      CURSOR OUR_RECORDS IS
      SELECT * FROM OUR_TABLE

BEGIN

      OPEN OUR_RECORDS;
      FETCH OUR_RECORDS BULK COLLECT INTO v_records;
      -- You may want to limit the number of records returned in
      -- in which case use the limit clause:
      -- FETCH OUR_RECORDS BULK COLLECT INTO v_records LIMIT 50;
      CLOSE OUR_RECORDS;

      RETURN (v_records);
 END;
```